# Knockout Jquery binding click does not work

Tags: jquery, binding, knockout.js, click

First question! Hope I do it well.

I have this bound list :

```html
<table id="restaurants_list" data-bind="foreach : restaurants" style="display: none">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:address.address1"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:address.address2"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:address.postcode + ' ' + address.suburb"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="show" data-bind="click: $root.showmap" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="map"></div>
```

And here the modelview :

```js
function RestaurantsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.restaurants = data;
    self.showMap = function (restaurant) {
        $("#map").show();
        ....
    };
    showMap(restaurants[0]);
};
```

Finally the binding :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#link_get_restaurants").bind("click", get_restaurants);
});
function get_restaurants(event) {
    $("#restaurants_list").show();
    ko.applyBindings(new RestaurantsViewModel());
}
```

The first `showmap(restaurants[0])` works fine.  But, the `click : $root.showmap` does not fire.

So did I do something wrong? I use Jquery as well, I don't know if it could come from that.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a type in your current sample: in your view model you have **showMap** with capital `M` but in your binding you have `click: $root.showmap` with lowercase `m`. Change it to `click: $root.showMap`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these 2 steps:

1) Replace

`click : $root.showmap`

with

```
click : $root.showMap
```

2) Curse the case sensitivity :)

Comment: Shame on me!!!!! Thanks a lot, 1 hour spent to look for a complicated mix between Jquery and Knockout!

Comment: Step 2 is very important!

Answer (score 2):

`showmap` is spelt wrong in the binding (your method is `showMap`). Can you try binding to `$root.showMap`?

```
<input type="button" value="show" data-bind="click: $root.showMap" />
```